# docker cp a folder with a relative symlink: invalid symlink

Tags: docker, symlink

In my container, I have a folder that contains a relative symlink to a parent's parent subfolder:

```
$ docker run --name symlink-test ubuntu bash -c "mkdir -p /1/2; touch /1/2/a; ln -s ../../usr /1/2; touch /1/2/z; ls -l /1/2"                                               :(
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar  4 03:37 a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 9 Mar  4 03:37 usr -> ../../usr
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar  4 03:37 z
```

I want to copy the folder `/1` to the host. However, I always get the following error:

```
$ docker cp symlink-test:/1/2
invalid symlink "/tmp/2/usr" -> "../../usr"
$ ls 2
a
```

Copying the files fails and `docker cp` aborts after it sees the symlink.

There are some Docker bugs related to this, but they are either fixed or were caused by something different:

- [FATA[0000] invalid symlink when copying a symlink with relative parent paths](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11394)
- [Error attempting to cp directory containing symlink](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7296)

I'm running Docker 1.10.2 on Fedora 23.

Is the above behavior of `docker cp` intended or is it a bug? If it is intended, what's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: What is the current WORKDIR in your container, when you are doing your docker cp?

Comment: The current WORKDIR is the default WORKDIR of the Ubuntu image, which is `/`.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I get it to work by:

```
docker cp -L container:/path/to/file.png current/directory/file.png
```

Comment: In the docs, '-L' is described as
 -L, --follow-link   Always follow symbol link in SRC_PATH

Answer (score 5):

I don't know whether this behavior is intentional, but here's a workaround:

```
docker cp my-container:/path/to/dir - | tar -x
```

Answer (score 4):

You could `docker exec -it <container> sh` then find the symlink of the file you want to copy `readlink -f symlinkName` and then `docker cp` that one instead.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The "docker cp -L " will fail on relative symlinks, you should fix them to be full path instead.

e.g.
invalid symlink "/tmp/2/usr" -> "../../usr"
usr is a relative symlink to ../../usr.
instead change it to: usr -> /full/path/to/usr/

another example:
invalid symlink "/working_folder/XXX/lib" -> "../../lib"

because: lib -> ../../lib/
fixed it: lib -> /full/path/to/lib/

and it will work by:
docker cp -L /full/path/to/working_folder:/working_folder/